# wicked pdf not displaying amazon s3 images

Tags: amazon-web-services, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

A very strange thing has happended to my app recently and not sure what has changed? wicked pdf is not longer displaying my `https://` images from my amazon s3 server. I am using the images with the `src= "https://pathtoimage.png"` and they were displaying just find before.

The displaying of images is not working locally or on heroku. On my production server, the pdf rendering is not working as well and creating a bunch of blank white pages.

I am using the gem

```
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
```

Comment: Install to 0.12.5 of wkhtmltopdf and see if that resolves the issue. There was a known issue with `https` image URLs prior to that version: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3001

Answer (score 2):

This is the fork of the wkmtltopdf-binary that worked for me: https://github.com/pallymore/wkhtmltopdf-binary.
Insert the following lines in your Gemfile:

`gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge', '~> 0.12.2.1'`

Answer (score 1):

Last 2 days i am facing the same problem. I have the version of wkhtmltopdf is 0.9.6. I have upgraded the version to 0.9.9. Now it's works fine.

I feel amazon might change something.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the version of wkhtmltopdf that comes bundled with the `wkhtmltopdf-binary`, `0.9.9` has this problem. Uninstalling the gem and then installing a newer binary such as `0.12.2.1` solved this issue for me.

I'm on OS X so I installed it with homebrew but there are binaries for other systems on [wkhtmltopdf.org](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)

Here's how to install a newer version of wkhtmltopdf with homebrew:

```
brew install cask
brew cask install wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: I am also having the same problem. I installed the latest gem version but also the problem continued to exist. The error says: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method