# Images not rendered with secure connection to Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, wicked-pdf

I am creating a PDF which contains images which are stored on Amazon S3.
My Rails application uses https, so also the URL to the S3 image is https, which is configured in `production.rb`:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_protocol => :https
}
```

The issue is that the S3 bucket has a security bucket policy that it only shows the image when it is coming from my web domain. This works well when showing the image in the view, because the referer is then my web domain which is whitelisted.

The issue when creating the PDF is that `wicked_pdf` tries to retrieve the image, but S3 can't see it is coming from my web domain and returns a `403 Forbidden`. So what can I do to solve this?

Comment: Are you able to view the image from S3 using https?

Comment: No, that is the question I'm asking :-)

Comment: Could you add some links to images that are accessible over http but fail over https?

Comment: The bucket policy is restricted to certain domain names, so you will not be able to open that link I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged your question with `wicked-pdf` I assume that's what you're using. It looks like this is a [known problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837231/wicked-pdf-not-displaying-amazon-s3-images) with some versions of that gem. The linked question gives several options to solve it.

Comment: Thanks, but I already use the version of that gem , with no result.

Comment: So http images load in a browser and in a PDF, but https images load in a browser but not in a PDF? In that case it seems like you should post the code you're using to generate the PDF, as well as the version of the gem (from `Gemfile.lock`).

Answer (score 1):

Is your CORS configured in AWS? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-cross-origin-resource-sharing/